# Scraping reader comment threads from globe and mail articles

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am interested in scraping reader comment threads from globe and mail articles (http://www.theglobeandmail.com/). For example, given the following comments page, I would like to have the output as shown below:

http://www.theglobeandmail.com/opinion/it-doesnt-matter-who-won-the-debate-america-has-already-lost/article32314064/comments/

**Output:**

Comment1
omigosh 2 days ago
I can't believe ...

Comment1.1
sirencall 2 days ago
In a basket ...

Comment1.2
Mr. Atoz 2 days ago
I agree completely. I had the same...

.
.
.
.

Comment2
David in Peachland 2 days ago
Holy crap! I spent 40 minutes of what’s left of my life...
.
.
.

I am using Python 3. I explored the following python libraries: scrapy, urllib, newspaper, BeautifulSoup. The problem is that the html page I get from the url does not contain the comment text. Below I explain how I am using scrapy.

With scrapy, I created a project named ScrapeNews

**scrapy startproject ScrapeNews**

Then I wrote the following code in the spider.

```
import scrapy

class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'news'
    start_urls = {
                    'http://www.theglobeandmail.com/opinion/it-doesnt-matter-who-won-the-debate-america-has-already-lost/article32314064/',
                    'http://www.theglobeandmail.com/opinion/it-doesnt-matter-who-won-the-debate-america-has-already-lost/article32314064/comments/'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        '''
        :param response:
        :return:
        '''
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'gnm-%s.html' %page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Then I ran the following, which created gnm-comments.html.

```
scrapy crawl news
```

I don't see the comment text or tag in this html at all. When I inspect comments on the webpage, I see that the comments have the tag:

```
<p class="comment">
```

But it doesn't show up in the html extracted using scrapy. 
I suspect that I am not scraping the right thing from the web.

Any ideas what might be going wrong? I will greatly appreciate relevant solutions, explanations or pointers.

Comment: SO helps people having issues with code, where is yours ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Gilles. Just included an excerpt of my code. (Sorry, I am new to SO and didn't know that I have to include the code here.)